# A question on Hall's proof that bipartite graphs imply the existence of matchings that saturate all vertices iff $|N(S)|\geq\left|S\right|$

Tags: algebraic-graph-theory

This is a question about the proof of the converse of Theorem 5.2 in
"Graph Theory with Applications" by J.A. Bondy and U.S.R. Murty, 1976,
North-Holland.

Theorem.  Let $G$ be a bipartite graph with bipartition $(X,Y)$.  Then $G$
contains a matching that saturates every vertex in $X$ if and only if

\begin{align*}
\forall S \subset X : \left|N(S)\right| \geq \left|S\right| \tag{5.2}                     
\end{align*}
Proof.  [...]

Conversely, suppose that $G$ is a bipartite graph satisfying (5.2), but
that $G$ contains no matching saturating all the vertices in $X$.  We shall
obtain a contradiction.  Let $M*$ be a maximum matching in $G$.  By our
supposition, $M*$ does not saturate all vertices in $X$.  Let $u$ be an
$M*$-unsaturated vertex in $X$, and let $Z$ denote the set of all vertices
connected to $u$ by $M*$-alternating paths.  Since $M*$ is a maximum matching,
it follows from theorem 5.1 that $u$ is the only $M*$-unsaturated vertex in
$Z$. [...]

Question.  How come $u$ is in $Z$?  $Z$ is the set of all vertices
connected to $u$.  But $u$ is not connected to itself because $G$ is
bipartite.  So there's no way $u$ could be in $Z$.  What's going on there?

Thank you!

Comment: You can define $Z$ to include $u$ also (taking an "alternating path" of size 0).  The point is that if $u$ is connected to another unsaturated node  via an alternating path, we could swap edges to increase the size of the matching by 1.

Comment: If you really dislike defining $u$ to be in $Z$, you can change the last sentence to "it follows from theorem 5.1 that [there are no] $M$*-unsaturated vertices in $Z$." [not counting $u$ itself] Note also that "connected via an alternating path" means it might be connected by a multi-hop path (not directly connected by a link in the graph).